# EntityFramework 6.2.0 Pregenrated View Templates - Method not found: HasIndex()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, t4

I'm using EF 6.2.0 codefirst in my Visual Studio 2015. I wanted to add pregenerated views to my project to improve speed. My model uses indexes defined through HasIndex() method of Fluent API.

Now upon trying to run the created TT template, I get an error:

> Error     Running transformation:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.MissingMethodException:
>   Method not found:
>   'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.IndexConfiguration
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration`1.HasIndex(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1>)'.

I have EF Community Power Tools extention installed.

I have copied my EF6 DLLs under Program Files Visual Studio path as suggested here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/EntityFramework6PowerTools/issues/22

What else can be done? Please help!

**Edit:**
**Resolution found!**

Install this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55259

Comment: It could be due to version mismatch or incompatibility. Try removing the references and add them via nuget.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh Remove what? All of my EF DLLs are already added through NuGet. Visual Studio supposedly isn't using those when working with TT templates tho, supposedly. That's why I was copying the DLLs to VS directory in Program Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you need updated EF 6.2 Tools for Visual Studio - I suggest you post an issue in the EF6 Github repo

Comment: Actually, yes... After some more search I've found that installing this helped:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55259